# Rename OOP tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

We currently have a tag for [object-oriented-paradigm](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/object-oriented-paradigm). Since OOP is conventionally defined as "object-oriented programming" (and is a programming paradigm), should the tag reflect as much? Would it need to be renamed, or synonymized with a new one?

We also have [functional-programming](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functional-programming), so the change would seem to create a consistency for how we tag different paradigms.

Comment: Whoops, my bad. Definitely should be changed. I created the original tag, before it was a couple different tags.

Comment: Definitely. Consistency allows for subtle tag differences down the line if we later need the name space. On a related note, how do we know if we have enough of a quorum to make a change?

Comment: I'd give it a day or two. If we don't get any objection, then I don't see any reason not to make the change.

Answer (score 7):

In order to remain consistent with other Stack Exchange sites, the best name for this tag is [object-oriented](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/object-oriented). This is the tag name used at:

- [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/object-oriented)
- [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/object-oriented)
- [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/object-oriented)

[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/oop/synonyms) also has [object-oriented](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/object-oriented) as a synonym of [oop](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oop).

By the [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment), it makes sense to use the same tag name as the majority of other Stack Exchange sites. It also makes migrations a bit easier if there are some matching tags, should that be necessary for any reason in future.

I'd wait and see if a synonym from [oop](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oop) is necessary—my feeling is that the tag guidance will help people find the right tag, so it might not yet be needed.

Comment: A nice thing about naming it "object-oriented" is that this will still pop up as a suggestion if the user is trying to type "object-oriented-programming". +1 from me for this and consistency.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, [object-oriented-programming](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/object-oriented-programming) has 27 characters, so it is too long to be created.

Shorter tags that are possible:
 [objectorientedprogramming](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/objectorientedprogramming), [object-oriented-program](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/object-oriented-program), [object-oriented](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/object-oriented)
,[oop](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oop)

Out of these, I'd say only  [objectorientedprogramming](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/objectorientedprogramming) is maybe better than [object-oriented-paradigm](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/object-oriented-paradigm), and the others are definitely worse and abuse the name more than "paradigm" does.

**Update:** Now the tag length limit is increased (to 35 characters), maybe renaming to [object-oriented-programming](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/object-oriented-programming) is a good idea.

Comment: Great point. Didn't even think of counting the characters. Seems like of those options, it's best to leave it as is.

Comment: For reference: CS uses [object-oriented], and Stack Overflow uses [oop] (with a synonym to [object-oriented]). It might be wise to have consistency here with the other sites if possible.

Comment: @Aurora0001 Also great points. How do we proceed with this? Is it too much to have three synonymous tags, keeping ours and using what CS/SO does as well? What's the best vehicle for reaching consensus on meta?

Comment: pleasedonotusetagnameswithwordsruntogethertheyreunreadable

Comment: @Peter I've posted an answer based on remaining consistent with the other sites. To get a consensus, let the most popular option rise to the top, and after a few days, the tags can be changed by anyone > 500 rep.

Comment: `Object-oriented` could cover programming and design. So seems like a good name.

Comment: @Peter Now the tag length limit is increased (to 35 characters), maybe renaming to [tag:object-oriented-programming] is a good idea (or adding a synonym). (I'm pinging you since you are a diamond mod, so you have the ability to add a synonym.)

Comment: @wythagoras Glad you returned XD. Next time a question tagged with object oriented programming is posted, we'll make a synonym